# Efficient code to move a node under another while keeping all HierarchyId's as integers and sequential

Tags: performance, beginner, entity-framework-core

I'm playing around with an app that will need to read Hierarchy trees quickly but will seldom modify them once created. I've chosen to use HierarchyIds with Entity Framework to model the hierarchy. I know it's not required, but the perfectionist in me would like to keep all HierarchyIds sequential and integers. This is the code I've developed to move a node under another. I'm pretty new to this, are there any places I can gain efficiency?

```
private static void MoveUnder(HTContext context, int nodeToMoveId, int newParentId)
{
    var nodeToMove = context.Nodes.Find(nodeToMoveId);
    var newParent = context.Nodes.Find(newParentId);

    // Check for a valid move
    if (newParent.HierarchyId == nodeToMove.HierarchyId || newParent.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(nodeToMove.HierarchyId))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Node can't be moved under its self");
    }

    // Used to collapse the hole left by moved node
    var siblingsWithGreaterHId = GetSiblingsWithGreaterHId(context, nodeToMove);

    // Used to figure out where to put moved node under new parent
    var newParentLastAddedChild = GetLastAddedChild(context, newParent);

    // get these before changing hierarchy ID of new node so we can update the subtree.
    var nodeToMoveDescendents = GetDescendents(context, nodeToMove);

    var oldRoot = nodeToMove.HierarchyId;
    var newRoot = newParent.HierarchyId.GetDescendant(newParentLastAddedChild.HierarchyId, null);

    // Move Node & Subtree
    nodeToMove.HierarchyId = newRoot;

    foreach (var descendent in nodeToMoveDescendents)
    {
        descendent.HierarchyId = descendent.HierarchyId.GetReparentedValue(oldRoot, newRoot);
    }

    // Move all siblings with greater HId back to fill gap.
    var newSiblingRoot = oldRoot;

    foreach (var sibling in siblingsWithGreaterHId)
    {
        var siblingDescendants = GetDescendents(context, sibling);

        var oldSiblingRoot = sibling.HierarchyId;
        sibling.HierarchyId = newSiblingRoot;

        foreach (var descendent in siblingDescendants)
        {
            descendent.HierarchyId = descendent.HierarchyId.GetReparentedValue(oldSiblingRoot, newSiblingRoot);
        }

        newSiblingRoot = oldSiblingRoot;
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}



private static Node GetLastAddedChild(HTContext context, Node node)
{
    return context.Nodes
        .Where(x => x.HierarchyId.GetAncestor(1) == node.HierarchyId)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.HierarchyId)
        .First();
}

private static List<Node> GetDescendents(HTContext context, Node node)
{
    return context.Nodes
        .Where(descendent => descendent.HierarchyId.IsDescendantOf(node.HierarchyId) && descendent.HierarchyId != node.HierarchyId)
        .ToList();
}

private static List<Node> GetSiblingsWithGreaterHId(HTContext context, Node node)
{
    return context.Nodes
        .Where(n => n.HierarchyId.GetAncestor(1) == node.HierarchyId.GetAncestor(1) && n.HierarchyId > node.HierarchyId)
        .ToList();
}

public class Node : EntityBase<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public HierarchyId HierarchyId { get; set; }
}
```

The code above works as I would like but I can't help thinking there would be ways to optimise it, specifically requiring less calls to the database.

Comment: Is this C# code? If so please add the C# language tag and perhaps .net.